# Как подписать андроид приложение

Tags: android, android-studio

Пишу приложение, но никто не может установить его без режима разрабочика и со включенной плей защитой. Можно ли обойти это не отдавая 25 вечнозеленых за лицензию разработчика на Google Play?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing тут все есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у Вас apk собирается как debug. Разумеется, что с сертификатом, который используется по умолчанию для debug приложение можно установить только из студии при включённом режиме разработчика.

Можно попробовать в студии сгенерировать самоподписанный сертификат. Если прокатит можно будет ставить приложение из apk. Правда плей может на него периодически ругаться.

> не отдавая 25 вечнозеленых за лицензию разработчика на Google Play

Есть ещё вариант в виде бесплатных магазинов приложений. Так их как например Яндекс Store. Но, у них на порядок меньше охват аудитории.

Comment: самоподпись делал, она тоже без разработчика не ставиться

Comment: есть же приложения, которых нет в play store, и они нормально ставяться по apk